# Error when testingElasticSearch apps via Cypress resulting in results not being populated - "[useElasticsearch] incorrect header check"

Tags: elasticsearch, cypress

We use Elastic Search throughout most of our app, and up until today, we've never had issues with testing those features via Cypress. One feature in our app is a calendar tool that populates a list with appointment dates and times. When accessing this calendar tool manually via Chrome, the list correctly populates without issue. When opening this tool during a Cypress spec, and ONLY during a Cypress spec, the results fail to load. The console spits out an error that just says "[useElasticsearch] incorrect header check" with no other information. In checking the network tab, we can confirm that the ES query is performed and returns results successfully, but the page is not updated with those results.

Note that this is NOT the result of a cy.request(), this error occurs through standard UI navigation. This issue, as I mentioned, ONLY occurs when testing via Cypress. Due to this, we are hesitant to make changes to the backend of the app, since it works perfectly fine in all other scenarios. This has been reproduced on Cypress versions 5.1.0, 6.1.0, 7.1.0, and 8.0.0. This has also been reproduced in Cypress when using the Chrome, Electron, and headless browsers.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Comment: If `useElasticsearch` is a React hook, you may need to add `cy.wait(0)` at an appropriate place in the test. Cypress sometimes does not release the front-end thread in a timely fashion and the hooks cannot complete.

Comment: The ElasticSearch results should populate on page load. Should I be adding the `cy.wait(0)` after the `cy.visit()` call, or elsewhere? I placed it after the visit call, but the same issue occurred.

Comment: After `cy.visit()` would be the place, so likely my guess was wrong. Would need to see code, both app and test. Can you post simplified examples?